# how to count the number divisible by N in given range (A to B) for multiple cases (C) in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

So basically, there are multiple cases that need to be solve by counting the number that divisible by N in given range A to B.

for example, there are 2 cases.

case 1 has A=1, B=10, N=3

case 2 has A=8, B=20, N=4

but on one condition that the input must be like this:

```
2        #<-- number of cases
1        #<-- A 
10       #<-- B 
3        #<-- N
8        #<-- A
20       #<-- B
4        #<-- N
```

the output will be like:

```
Case 1: 3 #because between 1 until 10, only 3,6,9 that divisible by 3
Case 2: 4 #because between 8 until 20, only 8,12,16,20 that divisible by 4
```

I have this function for reference:

```
def CountDiv(A,B,N):
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(A, B+1):
        if i % N == 0:
            count = count + 1
    
    return count
```

My explanation is bad but I just don't know how to make it more clearer. I hope someone will understand and enlightened me about this problem. Thank you

Comment: what is the problem that you have? it's seems that you have a function that does what you want...

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to optimize your algorithm ?

Comment: The number of integers in the range [A, B] that are divisible by N is: `B//N - (A-1)//N`

Comment: @UlisesBussi so what I'm asking is how to slice the A,B, and N from the input. like the example input and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CountDiv function works. So, I'm assuming that you are asking how to properly slice your input list. If you have your input sequence in a list, this should work

```
seq = [ 2,        #<-- number of cases
        1,        #<-- A 
        10,       #<-- B 
        3,        #<-- N
        8,        #<-- A
        20,       #<-- B
        4,        #<-- N
]


def slices(lst, n):

    number_of_cases = lst.pop(0)
    
    for i in range(0, n * number_of_cases, n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]


def CountDiv(A,B,N):
    
    count = 0
    for i in range(A, B+1):
        if i % N == 0:
            count = count + 1
    
    return count

print([CountDiv(*sub) for sub in [*slices(seq, n=3)]])
# [3, 4]
```

If you want the exact output you described, you can do this

```
for idx, sub in enumerate([*slices(seq, n=3)]):
    print(f"Case {idx}: {CountDiv(*sub)}")

# Case 0: 3
# Case 1: 4
```

You should also combine [@mozway's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70308190/7766834) and my answer, like so.

```
def slices(lst, n):
   
    number_of_cases = lst.pop(0)
     
    for i in range(0, n * number_of_cases, n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

def ndiv(A, B, N):
    return (B+N-(A+N-1)//N*N)//N if B>=A else 0

for idx, sub in enumerate([*slices(seq, n=3)]):
    print(f"Case {idx}: {ndiv(*sub)}")
```

**Edit on request**: The `*` operator is used twice above to [unpack elements from an iterable](https://towardsdatascience.com/unpacking-operators-in-python-306ae44cd480). For example, in the statement above, `ndiv(*sub)` could be replaced by `ndiv(sub[0], sub[1], sub[2])`. If we wanted to make it very verbose, we could write it like this

```
result_of_slicing = list(slices(seq, n= 3))
# [[1, 10, 3], [8, 20, 4]]

for index, a_slice in enumerate(result_of_slicing):

    A, B, N = a_slice
    result_of_ndiv = ndiv(A=A, B=B, N=N)
    
    print(f"Case {index}: {result_of_ndiv}")
    # Case 0: 3
    # Case 1: 4
```

Comment: can you explain to me what *slices and *sub mean? I'm still learning sorry. your answer is great but I want to understand it before I applied this method.

Comment: @GilangArindawa I have added a more verbose explanation of what the `*`operator does. Hope that helps!

Comment: oh I see, that helps alot. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Please consider marking the answer as correct if it answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop over all values. You can only generate the multiple from the smallest starting point (`(A+N-1)//N*N`):

```
def ndiv(A, B, N):
    return len(list((A+N-1)//N*N, B+1, N)))
```

Even better, calculate directly the number of values using:

```
def ndiv(A, B, N):
    if B<A:
        return 0
    return (B+N-(A+N-1)//N*N)//N
```

example:

```
>>> ndiv(8,20,4)
4

>>> ndiv(1,10,3)
3

>>> ndiv(1,1,3)
0
```